# Is it important to include status in Django?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, http-status-codes

I am working on project where I'm importing, parsing and showing JSON data on site. I wanted to ask if it's important to add in `JsonResponse` "status" attribute.

For example: `return JsonResponse({"details":"Data parsed successfully!"}, safe=False, status=200)`

Comment: Using `safe=False` is also not a good idea, that is important too since it makes the blob open to cross-site scripting.

Comment: Well I read an article where they said the it is almost always set to false. Because I'm parsing the JSON data it will come back as Dictionary only. With safe it can accept any form of JSON data. I know it might seem dangerous but on the other hand it is private project for myself to test my skills. Anyway thanks for your advice I will keep it in mind.

Comment: as long as the outer item is a dictionary, it is safe. That is exactly what `safe=True` checks: that the outer item is a dictionary. One should *not* return a list as outer object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is pretty much important. It might seem useless at the beginning, but it shows that you actually control what is happening and you can predict what can go wrong (actually most important!).

Status codes are universal and usually give fast feedback what went wrong without any further information. It's good practice to always add status to response that is sent from your application.